# middleware how to consolidate redundant code

Tags: express

I have 2 middleware that share the nested code. How do I move the `upload(req, res (err))` function out and call `upload` middleware?

```
exports.useMulterS3 = (req, res, next) => {
   
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    // do something
  })
  next()
}
exports.useMulter = (req, res, next) => {
   
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    // do something
  })
  next()
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more code? You've provided us with the bare minimum here.

Comment: I just want useMulterS3 and useMulter to share the same upload function. the upload function just checks for any errors (shared code).